# ng-click inside ng-repaat with animations,but event do not fire,why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-animation

[Here is the code in jsFiddler](http://jsbin.com/UMoVOFO/6/edit)

As you can see the code,when you click the add button ,I push a new item to the $scope.p,and every item in the ng-repeat has a event-binding,all the things works well,but when I add the attribute 'ng-animate',the event doesn't fire. thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2873) affecting ngAnimate in version 1.1.5 of AngularJS. You can solve it using a more recent version.

Your code will also work with version 1.1.5 if you load the jQuery library. 
[See updated code](http://jsbin.com/UqOQiFu/1/edit)

Comment: why if I add the jq libaray,that solve the issue?which mean Ag has a dependency of jq?

Comment: Angular contains a reduced jQuery implementation, called jqLite. If jQuery is not loaded in your code, andularJS will use its own jqLite, so it has no dependency on jQuery. However, if jQuery is available angularJs will use it, and this particular bug is related to jqLite, so simply adding jQuery to your code solves it because angular will use jQuery instead of its own jqLite.

Comment: It so kind of you to answer my Question,Best wishes!:D

Comment: another issue,if I do not reference jQuery,and use the lastest AngularJS,works fine ,but the animation got missed...so confused!